# Terraform and Azure Policy: Errors using "field": "Microsoft.KeyVault.Data/vaults/certificates/properties.validityInMonths"

Tags: azure, terraform, policy

Converting a built in policy into a custom one and running into this error using "field": "Microsoft.KeyVault.Data/vaults/certificates/properties.validityInMonths". It appears that this is only valid if you change the mode to "Built-In" not "All" which is what I have. Error says`"The provider 'Microsoft.KeyVault.Data' referenced by the 'field' property 'Microsoft.KeyVault.Data/vaults/certificates/properties.validityInMonths'`
of the policy rule doesn't exist." Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Key Vault policies are only built-ins at the moment.